# Android SDK file not found adb in flutter doctor(command prompt)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, sdk, adb

I have faced this issue how can I fix it? (I have downloaded the android sdk tool ,adb file is present in platform-tools directory)

This is the result of flutter doctor:

> C:\Windows\System32>flutter doctor -v
>
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable,
> 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139], locale en-IN)
> • Flutter version 1.22.2 at C:\Users\deepak\src\flutter
> • Framework revision 84f3d28555 (2 weeks ago), 2020-10-15 16:26:19 -0700
> • Engine revision b8752bbfff
> • Dart version 2.10.2
>
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.2)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\deepak\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\platform-tools
> • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
> • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\deepak\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\platform-tools
> X Android SDK file not found: adb.
> • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
> visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for
> detailed instructions.
> [!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
> X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
>
> [!] Connected device
> ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is occurring because you might not have installed **adb** in windows system. Please install abd in the system to resolve `Android SDK file not found: adb` issue.

As for `Flutter plugin not installed` you have to add `Flutter` in you Android Studio to resolve it. This will automatically install `Dart` plugin along with it.

You can refer the following link.
https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/